# Java Inner Classes Design Benefits

Tags: java, inner-classes

In java, you can have inner classes. I'm curious from a design perspective if there are any benefits to this.

My initial thoughts are that having a separate file with the class is cleaner in separating things into reusable modules. By doing so, if other classes wish to use that other class, they can also make their own instances. To me it seems like avoiding the inner classes may be a better design for extensibility and code reuse, and when working on new projects, its normally hard to tell if the class would be reused or not... so I feel siding on having the separate classes is the way to go.

I ask this question because I took over a project which has a bunch of these... which makes me think the previous developer may of just been lazy or unfamiliar with the IDE. But I want to make sure I'm not missing any benefits that these inner classes have. If there are benefits can someone let me know, and then I can confirm if the previous developer was taking advantage of these benefits.

Comment: Do you really mean inner classes, or [static] nested classes?

Comment: For one thing, inner class has access to members of the outer class, so sometimes it can help in objects/classes encapsulation (avoiding unnecessary getters and setters).

Comment: They were doing inner classes, but I welcome any comments about static nested classes too.

Comment: Builder pattern is based on inner classes for example. Guava also uses them a lot [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

Comment: Found something of interest, Effective Java Ch.4 Item 22 gives a nice break down of static member classes, nonstatic memeber classes, anonymous classes and local classes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Inner classes are good when they are not used outside the containing class - it's a way of curtailing class bloat. As a general rule, that's the only time I use them.

Non-static inner classes also have access to the containing instance's private fields.

Comment: I like the comment about class bloat. The issue I ran into is one file seemed to have like 10 of these, so the file was very long and I found separating the clases out seemed to make things easier for me to read...

Comment: Are there any benefits or detriments for testing?

Comment: Common sense always applied. If a class has 10 inner classes, chances are that the class has too much going on and should be split up into separate classes. This is true for any class that "seems too long", regardless of the number of inner classes.

Answer (score 3):

Inner classes are useful to:

1. Hide implementation details.
2. Make project view more concise and thus understandable.
3. Add logical grouping of the related code.

Answer (score 3):

One good usage of inner classes that comes into my mind is in [java.util.ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList) that hides its iterators implementations into `private inner classes`. You can't create them except by invoking `iterator()` or `listIterator()` on the list object.

This way the `Iterator` and `ListIterator` implementations for `ArrayList` are grouped with their related class and methods for enhanced readability (the implementations are pretty short), but hidden from others.

They can't be declared `static` as they need access to their enclosing **instance** object.

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
         implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {
    ...
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
         return new Itr();
    }

    private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    ...
    }

    public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
         return new ListItr(0);
    }

    private class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator<E> {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Non-static inner class:**
1) Inner class will be used to perform some task over the outer class and returns the output
. So it will ensure that the outer class object is created to access it.
2) Inner class is only specific to the outer class and no use on the outside world. So no need to think about code reuse.

e.g_1) The best example for inner class is `iterator` implementation of collection framework. Set(AbstractCollection.java) and List(AbstractList.java) will use different iterator inner class implementation. 
  -> We can reuse the inner class code. For example  implementation of `private class Itr` innerclass at `java.util.AbstractList` is used by both Arraylist and Vector.

**Static inner class:**
1) Static inner class won't depend on a outer class object; but it is specific to outer class level. It wont be exposed to standalone since it is specific to the outer class only. So no code reuse. 
2) It has group of methods which is common(shared) to all the objects (Class level) 
3)

e.g_1)  Sigleton object retrival using static inner class. 
e.g_2)  Builder Pattern  
e.g_3) Comparator implementation for a class .